# How to set style of header and footer with horizontal lines in \documentclass{scrbook}?

Tags: overleaf, scrbook

I want to add a header and footer for my file which is in `\documentclass{scrbook}`, how to do it?
I am using now for the header alone without lines `\pagestyle{headings}` but can't figure out how to add the lines and how to add a footer.

```
\documentclass{scrbook} % <= Druckversion: "scrbook", Bildschirmversion: "scrreprt"
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\newcommand\bcor{12mm} % <= Bindungskorrektur für Druckversion
\usepackage{osm-thesis}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{multirow, makecell, booktabs}
\usepackage{placeins}

\def\tabularxcolumn#1{m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}

\makeatletter
  \providecommand*\setfloatlocations[2]{\@namedef{fps@#1}{#2}}
\makeatother
\setfloatlocations{figure}{htbp}

\setfloatlocations{table}{htbp}


% DOCUMENT
%\KOMAoption{draft}{true} % <= z.B. zum "Debuggen" der Overfull-Boxes
\bibliography{thesis}


\begin{document}
    %\selectlanguage{ngerman}
    \selectlanguage{english}

% Einband
%\pagenumbering{alph}
%\ifisbook\include{content/coverpage}\fi
%\ifisbook\cleardoubleemptypage\fi

% (Haupt-)Titelseite, Abstract, ggf. Danksagung & Inhaltsverzeichnis
\pagenumbering{roman}
\include{content/titlepage}
% Eigenständigkeitserklärung
 



\ifisbook\pagestyle{plain}
\cleardoubleemptypage
\include{content/disclaimer}\fi
\ifisbook\cleardoubleemptypage\fi\include{content/abstract}
%\ifisbook\cleardoubleemptypage\fi\include{content/dedication}
%\tableofcontents


\tableofcontents


% Textteil
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\listoftables
\listoffigures
\pagestyle{headings}




\include{content/chapter1}
\include{content/chapter2}
\include{content/chapter3}
\include{content/chapter4}
\include{content/chapter5}
\include{content/chapter6}
\include{content/chapter7}
\include{content/chapter8}


\appendix\include{content/appendix} % example

% Bibliographie
\onecolumn{
\ifisbook\cleardoubleemptypage\fi
\phantomsection\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\refname}
\printbibliography[category=cited, title={References}]}



\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To enable the lines you can use KOMA options `headsepline` and `footsepline`.

```latex
\documentclass{scrbook}
\KOMAoptions{headsepline,footsepline}
\usepackage{blindtext}% only for dummy text
\begin{document}
\Blinddocument
\end{document}
```

If the footer should be modified, load package `scrlayer-scrpage`:

```latex
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage[automark]{scrlayer-scrpage}% sets page style scrheadings automatically
\KOMAoptions{%
  headsepline,footsepline,
  %plainheadsepline,% headsepline on plain pages too
  plainfootsepline
  }

\ifoot[plain page inner footer]{inner footer}
\cfoot*{centered footer}

\usepackage{blindtext}% only for dummy text
\begin{document}
\Blinddocument
\end{document}
```

Note: if package `scrlayer-scrpage` is loaded, page style `headings` is only an alias of layer page style `scrheadings`.

Comment: Great! but how to make the footer to the half of the page not to the cross the whole page?

Comment: `\setfootsepline` is deprecated and `.4pt` is the default line width of the line in the footer. If you want to change `footwidth` and align the footer to the inner margin use option `footwidth=0.5\textwidth:0pt`. If only the line in the footer should be shorten: `footsepline=:0.5\textwidth` or `footsepline=0.4pt:0.5\textwidth`. If the page number should be on the inner side: `\ofoot*{}\ifoot*{\pagemark}`. Or maybe you ask a new question and explain the desired result.

Comment: Great! worked as needed. Millions of thanks :)